# cannot access directive's scope object in directive's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, angularjs-scope

MaterialIn.directive.js

```
angular.module('mdt')
    .directive('mdtMaterialins', materialInsDirective);

function materialInsDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            materialoffers: '=',

        },
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/materialOffers/materialIns/materialIns.html',
        controllerAs: 'materialInsVm',
        controller: MaterialinsController
    };
}
function MaterialinsController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
console.log(vm);  //shows the materialoffers object present
console.log(vm.materialoffers);  //show undefined

}
```

Hi everyone.i made a directive and send it an array of objects "materialoffers",i can access it on the html page it is working fine,but idk why i cant access it inside the controller,it shows undefined,can anyone please tell me a way i can use that materialoffers inside the controller,i want to get its length and store it in a $scope variable like this

```
vm.total=vm.materialoffers.length;
```

Comment: How did you use `mdtMaterialins` directive? Did you confirm that the `materialoffers` has set the value in parent controller? I dont see any issues with your code.

Comment: yes ,i am using materialoffers in the template and it is working but it is undefined in the controller although when i log the whole controller (vm) it shows that there is materialoffers present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `materialoffers` variable may get its value after a $http call or similar, as in it doesn't instantly have a value when the directive is created. The `console.log(vm)` shows the variable since it shows the state of the object (vm in this case) when you click it. You can test this phenomenon with the following code in your browser console:

```
var object = {};
object; // logs the object in console, shows an empty object
window.setTimeout(function() {
    object.testValue = "test value"
}, 10000) // After 10 seconds, the object will get the property testValue
```

If you click the object before the 10 seconds have passed, it won't have the property, but after you click on it after 10 seconds, you will see the added property there.

Try replacing your controller code with this:

```
function MaterialinsController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$watch(function() { return vm.materialoffers }, function() {
        console.log(vm.materialoffers)
    });
}
```

Comment: If an answer helped to solve your problem, please mark it as a selected answer so it's seen as resolved.

Comment: i voted the answer but since my reputation is less than 15 it doesnt show

Comment: I mean select the answer as correct by clicking on the check mark below the vote buttons, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers